# Prove that $\lim_{x\to1} \frac {\sin (\pi x)}{x-1}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to prove that $\lim_{x\to1} \frac {\sin (\pi x)}{x-1}$.

I think I can use this rule: $\lim_{h\to0} \frac {\sin h}{h} = 1$ but I really got stuck with what I need to substitute here.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Hello, how about using $h=x-1$?

Comment: Consider rewriting your question. You cannot "prove that $b^2$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the substitution $h=x-1$. Then, we have

$$\begin{align*}\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x-1}&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin(\pi (h+1))}{h}\\\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(\pi h+\pi))}{h}\\\\  
&=-\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(\pi h))}{h}\\\\  
&=-\pi\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(\pi h))}{\pi h}\\\\
&=-\pi\\\\
\implies\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x-1}&=-\pi\end{align*}$$

Comment: Please fix your typos. (Edit link below)

Comment: Should be good now

Comment: Not at all, there's no L Hoptial nor indeterminant.

Comment: How does L'Hopital's not work?

Comment: It does, but I think the OP wanted to solve the question using the definition of a limit. I gave L'Hoptial's rule as an alternate way to show the limit but I guess someone thought otherwise

Comment: Thanks! That was the way I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Considering the gradient between two points $(a, f(a))$ and $(x, f(x))$, and then moving $x$ towards $a$ so that they are infinitesimally close, $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} = f'(a)$. Hence:

$$\lim_{x\to1} \frac {\sin (\pi x)}{x-1} = \lim_{x\to1} \frac {\sin (\pi x) - \sin(\pi\cdot1)}{x-1}= \sin'(\pi x) |_{x=1} = \pi \cos(\pi) = -\pi$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{gather*}
\lim _{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{\sin \pi x}{x-1}\\
Let\ x=1+h,\ then\ as\ x\rightarrow 1,\ h\rightarrow 0\\
\lim _{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{\sin \pi x}{x-1} =\lim _{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin \pi ( 1+h)}{h} =\lim _{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{-\sin \pi h}{\pi h} \cdotp \pi =-\pi 
\end{gather*}

Answer (score 1):

Let's use the definition of the derivative :
$$f'(a)=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$
In our case $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)$, hence $f'(x)=\pi\cos(\pi x)$ :

and $a=1$ :

So :
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\sin(\pi x)-\sin (\pi)}{x-1}&=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x-1}\\
&=f'(1)\\
&=\pi \cos(\pi\times 1)\\
&=-\pi
\end{align}
Since $\cos(\pi)=-1$.

Therefore our limit :
$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x-1}=-\pi$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $h=\pi(x-1)$ so that $\pi x=h+\pi$. Then

$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x-1}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{-\sin(h)}{\dfrac h\pi}.$$

Comment: Can the kind downvoter justify ?